Assertion of a private final field
I have a service with a private final hashmap as a cache. People access this service to fetch some information. Everytime a user triggers this the cache might be updated if some time has passed or the user visits the service for the first time.
User A triggers the service and his information is stored within the cache.
User B triggers also the service and his information is stored within the cache as well.
Both users never get the information about other users.
For my unit test I want to check that both information are held within the cache.
I know that I could access the data using reflection in the test.
But are there any other ways accessing the data?
I'm using mockito by the way.
I don't want to increase the visibility of the field.
I don't want to expose the information using a package private getter method.
I don't want to inject the cache using spring bean configuration mechanism.
Update: I'm aware that with all the restrictions set, I'm limited in my options. I just want to see if I'm missing something I've never been thinking about or maybe there are some features of jigsaw oder mockito I'm not aware of. Mockito has already some features which help inspecting internals like Spy oder Captor, but Spy cannot be applied on final fields.

"I don't want to increase the visibility of the field. I don't want to expose the information using a package private getter method. I don't want to inject the cache using spring bean configuration mechanism."  Too bad.  You will almost certainly have to do one of those three things.

I am no expert on testing. But my understanding is that generally we want to be testing effects not internals. What is the purpose of the class, the outcomes? Test those. We should be able to refactor the implementation without altering the test. Furthermore, we would likely want to expose some of this contained information to manage runtime, such as through [Java Management Extensions (JMX)](Java Management Extensions). Tracking users’ access is something we would want to see at runtime. So those points of JMX exposure should provide good access for your tests, in this particular case.

We should be able to refactor the implementation without altering the test - Ideals are nice. And do not survive contact with reality. This boils down to 'unit tests bad'. The ideology sounds fantastic, but [A] you want to test self-contained aspects (where it's just a memoizable 'this input should lead to that output', no deps on anything more), because simple, fast, obvious, and [B] sometimes such methods are a part of a larger job, and they exist solely for that job, i.e. should be private. Which therefore means [C] nice ideology but does not lead to good code.

maybe using AspectJ or other code weaving technology (but I must agree with previous comment(s) - unit testing is used to validate behavior, not internal details/implementation - the caching may be changed, externalized, ... ; maybe you can separate caching and information gathering, so to be able to test if the service is asking for information [or using the cached data])

What you want is simply not how java works.
The best available compromise is the following:

Always put any test code that tests a specific class (e.g. a unit test; any other test, such as an integration test, has no business testing stuff you intend to be private so the point is moot for anything else) in the exact same package. That does not mean you have to intermingle your test classes with your main classes; you can eg. have src/main/my/pkg/MyCache.java with the actual code, and src/test/my/pkg/TestMyCache.java which tests it; they are both in package my.pkg but not in the same source dir.

With that setup, your test code can see and call any package private entities in MyCache. Thus, make whatever you want to test package private (no access modifier at all; just void foo() {} (no public / protected / private).

You may want to annotate the method as @VisibleForTesting. This annotation isn't in core java but lots of utility repositories do have it. From the API-wise fairly well designed guava to jetbrains' "box-o-annotations" library. These annotations don't do anything themselves, but they are, at least, human readable (they literally say "Visible for testing"), and various tools might be aware of these annotations. This is what annotations are for. Comments that tools can read. For example, it is not difficult to write some tools that check if you invoke a @VisibleForTesting method from outside the source file and not from a src/test root. Indeed, many IDEs perform this automatically; they know what these annotations mean. You'll need to add a dependency to a project with such an annotation (or write it yourself); note that android development has some guava-esque thing included out of the box, and that includes @VisibleForTesting.


Reflection isn't the right answer even if you wanted to; it creates difficult to read code, and JDK21+ basically breaks reflection (well, it still does what the spec now says, but that spec filled in rather a lot of blanks, and causes all sorts of trouble once you involve module systems and the lot. You.. don't wanna go there except as measure of very last resort).
But I really don't want to!
Then you can't test your method at all.

You don't need to check the contents of the map - that would be testing the implementation of Map to an extent, which is simply not needed. Verify the behaviour instead.
Write the class in way which allows testing. Consider this simplified example of your service:
public class MyService {

  private final Map<String, Integer> cache;

  public MyService(Map<String, Integer> cache) {
    this.cache = cache;
  }

  public MyService() {
    this(new HashMap<>());
  }

  public void store(String user, Integer data) {
    cache.put(user, data);
  }
}

In the test verify the interactions with the mock and you don't need to expose the internals of the class. If you are worried about the cache instance being leaked, you can just make a defensive copy in the constructor.
public class MyServiceTests {

  @Test
  public void test() {
    Map<String, Integer> cache = mock();
    MyService myService = new MyService(cache);
    myService.store("A", 1);
    myService.store("B", 2);

    verify(cache, times(1)).put("A", 1);
    verify(cache, times(1)).put("B", 2);
  }
}

Like this you have verified the behaviour of your cache, without exposing internals in any way and without testing, if Map is implemented correctly (which is done already by the jdk team).

This doesn't actually answer the question. Instead it peddles an ideology that supposed leads to the question being moot. I'm not disagreeing with the ideology, to be clear. But it's still not an answer to the question.

@rzwitserloot Respectfully, but I disagree, it answers the question with an option, which is not among the ones OP is unhappy with (at least at the moment). The cache is already private and final, meaning it must be instantiated in the constructor.  So adding a constructor accepting the map (if one does not exist already) is the simplest solution, which does not increase field visibility, does not add package private getter, does not use spring and does not use reflection.
